# Updating Windows 10 Build

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have 8 PCs that have Windows 10 pro build 18362.

I would ideally like to downgrade/upgrade them to Windows 10 LSTC 1904 in place.

If I can't do that then I would like to upgrade to Windows 10 Enterprise 1904 with an inplace upgrade.

**Reasons**

Internal requirement, I have no choice. Machines must be within Microsoft support period.

**Constraints:**
No access to the internet
Access to KMS server only (no packages present)
Application software that prevents new install of OS.

How do i do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "Application software that prevents new install of OS"? What software? Or rather, are your windows updates options disabled for you as a user because your Windows updates are controlled by your domain administrator?

Comment: @Mastaxx the machines run vision systems, we dont know how a clean install will affect the applications interactions with the  camera drivers